# Altair distance between bar labels in mark_text

Tags: python, bar-chart, visualization, altair

Help me with my grouped stacked bar plot. I can't set distances between bar labels in altair.

This is my code

```
chart = alt.Chart(chain_and_prices_for_bar, title='Распределение средних цен различных ценовых категорий среди аптечных сетей в разрезе страны производства').mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('category_of_price:N', stack='zero', sort=['Низкая', 'Ниже среднего', 'Средняя', 'Выше среднего', 'Высокая', 'Самая высокая'], title=None, axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=-45, labelOverlap=False)),
    y=alt.Y('mean_price_of_medicine:Q', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False, title='Суммарная средняя цена'), scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 201], bins=[i for i in range(211) if i%10 ==0])),
    #column=alt.Column('retail_chain:N', title=None, sort=list_of_top_pharmacies, header=alt.Header(labelFontSize=11, labelFontStyle='bold')),
    order=alt.Order(
      'is_import', sort='ascending'),
    color=alt.Color('is_import:N', scale=alt.Scale(range=['#96ceb4', '#ffcc5c']),
        legend=alt.Legend(title='Страна производства'))
    ).properties(
        width=100,
        height=600)

#chart = chart.configure_view(strokeOpacity=0)
chart.configure_title(fontSize=18, anchor='middle', align='center', dy=-10)
    
text = alt.Chart(chain_and_prices_for_bar).mark_text(dx=-1, dy=2, color='black', align='center', baseline='bottom', angle=270).encode(
    x=alt.X('category_of_price:N', stack='zero', sort=['Низкая', 'Ниже среднего', 'Средняя', 'Выше среднего', 'Высокая', 'Самая высокая'], title=None, axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=-45, labelOverlap=False)),
    y=alt.Y('mean_price_of_medicine:Q'),
    detail='retail_chain:N',
    text=alt.Text('mean_price_of_medicine:Q', format='.2f'))

alt.layer(
    chart, text, data=chain_and_prices_for_bar).facet(
    facet=alt.Column('retail_chain:N', title=None, sort=list_of_top_pharmacies, header=alt.Header(labelFontSize=11, labelFontStyle='bold')),
).configure_view(continuousHeight=200, continuousWidth= 0.5).configure_facet(spacing=0.5)
```

This is what i got

[image]

numbers are overlapping and i need to change it

```
chain_and_prices_for_bar = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
list_of_top_pharmacies = ['Гродненское РУП Фармация', 'Альфа-аптека', 'Планета Здоровья', 'Моя Аптека', 'Остров здоровья', 'Биотест', 'Искамед', 'ADEL','Inlek']
```

> my_dict = {'retail_chain': {0: 'ADEL',
> 34: 'Альфа-аптека',
> 72: 'Моя Аптека',
> 36: 'Биотест',
> 38: 'Биотест',
> 86: 'Остров здоровья',
> 40: 'Биотест',
> 42: 'Биотест',
> 84: 'Остров здоровья',
> 44: 'Биотест',
> 46: 'Биотест',
> 82: 'Моя Аптека',
> 48: 'Гродненское РУП Фармация',
> 50: 'Гродненское РУП Фармация',
> 80: 'Моя Аптека',
> 52: 'Гродненское РУП Фармация',
> 106: 'Планета Здоровья',
> 54: 'Гродненское РУП Фармация',
> 56: 'Гродненское РУП Фармация',
> 78: 'Моя Аптека',
> 58: 'Гродненское РУП Фармация',
> 60: 'Искамед',
> 76: 'Моя Аптека',
> 62: 'Искамед',
> 64: 'Искамед',
> 74: 'Моя Аптека',
> 66: 'Искамед',
> 68: 'Искамед',
> 32: 'Альфа-аптека',
> 90: 'Остров здоровья',
> 88: 'Остров здоровья',
> 98: 'Планета Здоровья',
> 2: 'ADEL',
> 104: 'Планета Здоровья',
> 4: 'ADEL',
> 6: 'ADEL',
> 102: 'Планета Здоровья',
> 8: 'ADEL',
> 10: 'ADEL',
> 100: 'Планета Здоровья',
> 12: 'Inlek',
> 14: 'Inlek',
> 30: 'Альфа-аптека',
> 16: 'Inlek',
> 18: 'Inlek',
> 70: 'Искамед',
> 96: 'Планета Здоровья',
> 20: 'Inlek',
> 28: 'Альфа-аптека',
> 92: 'Остров здоровья',
> 22: 'Inlek',
> 94: 'Остров здоровья',
> 24: 'Альфа-аптека',
> 26: 'Альфа-аптека',
> 105: 'Планета Здоровья',
> 73: 'Моя Аптека',
> 89: 'Остров здоровья',
> 75: 'Моя Аптека',
> 103: 'Планета Здоровья',
> 93: 'Остров здоровья',
> 87: 'Остров здоровья',
> 83: 'Моя Аптека',
> 101: 'Планета Здоровья',
> 79: 'Моя Аптека',
> 99: 'Планета Здоровья',
> 85: 'Остров здоровья',
> 95: 'Остров здоровья',
> 81: 'Моя Аптека',
> 97: 'Планета Здоровья',
> 77: 'Моя Аптека',
> 91: 'Остров здоровья',
> 53: 'Гродненское РУП Фармация',
> 69: 'Искамед',
> 27: 'Альфа-аптека',
> 25: 'Альфа-аптека',
> 23: 'Inlek',
> 21: 'Inlek',
> 19: 'Inlek',
> 17: 'Inlek',
> 29: 'Альфа-аптека',
> 15: 'Inlek',
> 11: 'ADEL',
> 9: 'ADEL',
> 7: 'ADEL',
> 5: 'ADEL',
> 3: 'ADEL',
> 1: 'ADEL',
> 13: 'Inlek',
> 31: 'Альфа-аптека',
> 33: 'Альфа-аптека',
> 35: 'Альфа-аптека',
> 67: 'Искамед',
> 65: 'Искамед',
> 63: 'Искамед',
> 61: 'Искамед',
> 59: 'Гродненское РУП Фармация',
> 57: 'Гродненское РУП Фармация',
> 55: 'Гродненское РУП Фармация',
> 51: 'Гродненское РУП Фармация',
> 49: 'Гродненское РУП Фармация',
> 47: 'Биотест',
> 45: 'Биотест',
> 43: 'Биотест',
> 41: 'Биотест',
> 39: 'Биотест',
> 37: 'Биотест',
> 71: 'Искамед',
> 107: 'Планета Здоровья'},
> 'category_of_price': {0: 'Низкая',
> 34: 'Самая высокая',
> 72: 'Низкая',
> 36: 'Низкая',
> 38: 'Ниже среднего',
> 86: 'Ниже среднего',
> 40: 'Средняя',
> 42: 'Выше среднего',
> 84: 'Низкая',
> 44: 'Высокая',
> 46: 'Самая высокая',
> 82: 'Самая высокая',
> 48: 'Низкая',
> 50: 'Ниже среднего',
> 80: 'Высокая',
> 52: 'Средняя',
> 106: 'Самая высокая',
> 54: 'Выше среднего',
> 56: 'Высокая',
> 78: 'Выше среднего',
> 58: 'Самая высокая',
> 60: 'Низкая',
> 76: 'Средняя',
> 62: 'Ниже среднего',
> 64: 'Средняя',
> 74: 'Ниже среднего',
> 66: 'Выше среднего',
> 68: 'Высокая',
> 32: 'Высокая',
> 90: 'Выше среднего',
> 88: 'Средняя',
> 98: 'Ниже среднего',
> 2: 'Ниже среднего',
> 104: 'Высокая',
> 4: 'Средняя',
> 6: 'Выше среднего',
> 102: 'Выше среднего',
> 8: 'Высокая',
> 10: 'Самая высокая',
> 100: 'Средняя',
> 12: 'Низкая',
> 14: 'Ниже среднего',
> 30: 'Выше среднего',
> 16: 'Средняя',
> 18: 'Выше среднего',
> 70: 'Самая высокая',
> 96: 'Низкая',
> 20: 'Высокая',
> 28: 'Средняя',
> 92: 'Высокая',
> 22: 'Самая высокая',
> 94: 'Самая высокая',
> 24: 'Низкая',
> 26: 'Ниже среднего',
> 105: 'Высокая',
> 73: 'Низкая',
> 89: 'Средняя',
> 75: 'Ниже среднего',
> 103: 'Выше среднего',
> 93: 'Высокая',
> 87: 'Ниже среднего',
> 83: 'Самая высокая',
> 101: 'Средняя',
> 79: 'Выше среднего',
> 99: 'Ниже среднего',
> 85: 'Низкая',
> 95: 'Самая высокая',
> 81: 'Высокая',
> 97: 'Низкая',
> 77: 'Средняя',
> 91: 'Выше среднего',
> 53: 'Средняя',
> 69: 'Высокая',
> 27: 'Ниже среднего',
> 25: 'Низкая',
> 23: 'Самая высокая',
> 21: 'Высокая',
> 19: 'Выше среднего',
> 17: 'Средняя',
> 29: 'Средняя',
> 15: 'Ниже среднего',
> 11: 'Самая высокая',
> 9: 'Высокая',
> 7: 'Выше среднего',
> 5: 'Средняя',
> 3: 'Ниже среднего',
> 1: 'Низкая',
> 13: 'Низкая',
> 31: 'Выше среднего',
> 33: 'Высокая',
> 35: 'Самая высокая',
> 67: 'Выше среднего',
> 65: 'Средняя',
> 63: 'Ниже среднего',
> 61: 'Низкая',
> 59: 'Самая высокая',
> 57: 'Высокая',
> 55: 'Выше среднего',
> 51: 'Ниже среднего',
> 49: 'Низкая',
> 47: 'Самая высокая',
> 45: 'Высокая',
> 43: 'Выше среднего',
> 41: 'Средняя',
> 39: 'Ниже среднего',
> 37: 'Низкая',
> 71: 'Самая высокая',
> 107: 'Самая высокая'},
> 'is_import': {0: 'Беларусь',
> 34: 'Беларусь',
> 72: 'Беларусь',
> 36: 'Беларусь',
> 38: 'Беларусь',
> 86: 'Беларусь',
> 40: 'Беларусь',
> 42: 'Беларусь',
> 84: 'Беларусь',
> 44: 'Беларусь',
> 46: 'Беларусь',
> 82: 'Беларусь',
> 48: 'Беларусь',
> 50: 'Беларусь',
> 80: 'Беларусь',
> 52: 'Беларусь',
> 106: 'Беларусь',
> 54: 'Беларусь',
> 56: 'Беларусь',
> 78: 'Беларусь',
> 58: 'Беларусь',
> 60: 'Беларусь',
> 76: 'Беларусь',
> 62: 'Беларусь',
> 64: 'Беларусь',
> 74: 'Беларусь',
> 66: 'Беларусь',
> 68: 'Беларусь',
> 32: 'Беларусь',
> 90: 'Беларусь',
> 88: 'Беларусь',
> 98: 'Беларусь',
> 2: 'Беларусь',
> 104: 'Беларусь',
> 4: 'Беларусь',
> 6: 'Беларусь',
> 102: 'Беларусь',
> 8: 'Беларусь',
> 10: 'Беларусь',
> 100: 'Беларусь',
> 12: 'Беларусь',
> 14: 'Беларусь',
> 30: 'Беларусь',
> 16: 'Беларусь',
> 18: 'Беларусь',
> 70: 'Беларусь',
> 96: 'Беларусь',
> 20: 'Беларусь',
> 28: 'Беларусь',
> 92: 'Беларусь',
> 22: 'Беларусь',
> 94: 'Беларусь',
> 24: 'Беларусь',
> 26: 'Беларусь',
> 105: 'Импорт',
> 73: 'Импорт',
> 89: 'Импорт',
> 75: 'Импорт',
> 103: 'Импорт',
> 93: 'Импорт',
> 87: 'Импорт',
> 83: 'Импорт',
> 101: 'Импорт',
> 79: 'Импорт',
> 99: 'Импорт',
> 85: 'Импорт',
> 95: 'Импорт',
> 81: 'Импорт',
> 97: 'Импорт',
> 77: 'Импорт',
> 91: 'Импорт',
> 53: 'Импорт',
> 69: 'Импорт',
> 27: 'Импорт',
> 25: 'Импорт',
> 23: 'Импорт',
> 21: 'Импорт',
> 19: 'Импорт',
> 17: 'Импорт',
> 29: 'Импорт',
> 15: 'Импорт',
> 11: 'Импорт',
> 9: 'Импорт',
> 7: 'Импорт',
> 5: 'Импорт',
> 3: 'Импорт',
> 1: 'Импорт',
> 13: 'Импорт',
> 31: 'Импорт',
> 33: 'Импорт',
> 35: 'Импорт',
> 67: 'Импорт',
> 65: 'Импорт',
> 63: 'Импорт',
> 61: 'Импорт',
> 59: 'Импорт',
> 57: 'Импорт',
> 55: 'Импорт',
> 51: 'Импорт',
> 49: 'Импорт',
> 47: 'Импорт',
> 45: 'Импорт',
> 43: 'Импорт',
> 41: 'Импорт',
> 39: 'Импорт',
> 37: 'Импорт',
> 71: 'Импорт',
> 107: 'Импорт'},
> 'mean_price_of_medicine': {0: 4.92,
> 34: 78.74,
> 72: 5.1,
> 36: 5.09,
> 38: 15.15,
> 86: 14.92,
> 40: 25.95,
> 42: 38.38,
> 84: 5.37,
> 44: 48.12,
> 46: 84.02,
> 82: 83.49,
> 48: 5.28,
> 50: 15.13,
> 80: 49.23,
> 52: 26.11,
> 106: 86.08,
> 54: 38.06,
> 56: 49.25,
> 78: 37.33,
> 58: 83.79,
> 60: 5.18,
> 76: 26.22,
> 62: 15.19,
> 64: 26.29,
> 74: 14.81,
> 66: 38.48,
> 68: 48.93,
> 32: 47.22,
> 90: 38.31,
> 88: 25.82,
> 98: 15.17,
> 2: 15.21,
> 104: 50.87,
> 4: 26.52,
> 6: 38.14,
> 102: 37.9,
> 8: 46.43,
> 10: 89.32,
> 100: 25.85,
> 12: 5.14,
> 14: 15.01,
> 30: 38.04,
> 16: 26.16,
> 18: 38.56,
> 70: 93.85,
> 96: 5.06,
> 20: 47.71,
> 28: 26.08,
> 92: 50.44,
> 22: 88.74,
> 94: 86.42,
> 24: 5.29,
> 26: 14.98,
> 105: 48.25,
> 73: 7.21,
> 89: 26.74,
> 75: 15.85,
> 103: 37.83,
> 93: 49.03,
> 87: 16.1,
> 83: 87.7,
> 101: 26.52,
> 79: 38.01,
> 99: 16.33,
> 85: 7.03,
> 95: 82.19,
> 81: 48.59,
> 97: 7.17,
> 77: 26.46,
> 91: 38.22,
> 53: 26.42,
> 69: 48.85,
> 27: 15.86,
> 25: 7.32,
> 23: 87.21,
> 21: 48.81,
> 19: 38.58,
> 17: 26.51,
> 29: 26.55,
> 15: 16.06,
> 11: 83.96,
> 9: 48.56,
> 7: 38.32,
> 5: 26.66,
> 3: 16.1,
> 1: 7.33,
> 13: 7.21,
> 31: 38.03,
> 33: 48.07,
> 35: 94.97,
> 67: 38.34,
> 65: 26.62,
> 63: 16.09,
> 61: 7.22,
> 59: 95.27,
> 57: 48.59,
> 55: 38.14,
> 51: 16.14,
> 49: 6.9,
> 47: 89.96,
> 45: 48.1,
> 43: 38.06,
> 41: 26.7,
> 39: 16.12,
> 37: 7.17,
> 71: 108.55,
> 107: 86.54},
> 'divided_mean_price_of_medicine': {0: 2.46,
> 34: 39.37,
> 72: 2.55,
> 36: 2.54,
> 38: 7.57,
> 86: 7.46,
> 40: 12.98,
> 42: 19.19,
> 84: 2.68,
> 44: 24.06,
> 46: 42.01,
> 82: 41.75,
> 48: 2.64,
> 50: 7.56,
> 80: 24.61,
> 52: 13.05,
> 106: 43.04,
> 54: 19.03,
> 56: 24.62,
> 78: 18.67,
> 58: 41.89,
> 60: 2.59,
> 76: 13.11,
> 62: 7.6,
> 64: 13.15,
> 74: 7.41,
> 66: 19.24,
> 68: 24.46,
> 32: 23.61,
> 90: 19.16,
> 88: 12.91,
> 98: 7.59,
> 2: 7.6,
> 104: 25.44,
> 4: 13.26,
> 6: 19.07,
> 102: 18.95,
> 8: 23.22,
> 10: 44.66,
> 100: 12.92,
> 12: 2.57,
> 14: 7.5,
> 30: 19.02,
> 16: 13.08,
> 18: 19.28,
> 70: 46.92,
> 96: 2.53,
> 20: 23.86,
> 28: 13.04,
> 92: 25.22,
> 22: 44.37,
> 94: 43.21,
> 24: 2.65,
> 26: 7.49,
> 105: 24.12,
> 73: 3.6,
> 89: 13.37,
> 75: 7.92,
> 103: 18.92,
> 93: 24.51,
> 87: 8.05,
> 83: 43.85,
> 101: 13.26,
> 79: 19.0,
> 99: 8.17,
> 85: 3.52,
> 95: 41.09,
> 81: 24.3,
> 97: 3.58,
> 77: 13.23,
> 91: 19.11,
> 53: 13.21,
> 69: 24.43,
> 27: 7.93,
> 25: 3.66,
> 23: 43.6,
> 21: 24.4,
> 19: 19.29,
> 17: 13.26,
> 29: 13.28,
> 15: 8.03,
> 11: 41.98,
> 9: 24.28,
> 7: 19.16,
> 5: 13.33,
> 3: 8.05,
> 1: 3.67,
> 13: 3.6,
> 31: 19.01,
> 33: 24.04,
> 35: 47.48,
> 67: 19.17,
> 65: 13.31,
> 63: 8.04,
> 61: 3.61,
> 59: 47.63,
> 57: 24.3,
> 55: 19.07,
> 51: 8.07,
> 49: 3.45,
> 47: 44.98,
> 45: 24.05,
> 43: 19.03,
> 41: 13.35,
> 39: 8.06,
> 37: 3.59,
> 71: 54.27,
> 107: 43.27}}

Comment: It's a good idea to create an [mre] when asking a question so that it is quicker for others to help

Comment: i can't hide my dict in code snipped because i get error "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Thanks for posting your data. I tried running your code with it but I can't because there are undefined variables an unmatches parentheses. It is usually better to take away everything that is not relevant to the question and use and example data set, e.g. one from the gallery and create an [mre]. I understand it can be hard to figure out how to do that so I tried to answer what I think your question is below and added an example with stacked text in a faceted (grouped) chart. See if that is what you are looking for

Comment: i updated post with added variable, but you just could delete "sort" it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of this in [the docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/stacked_bar_chart_with_text.html):

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source=data.barley()

bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('sum(yield):Q', stack='zero'),
    y=alt.Y('variety:N'),
    color=alt.Color('site')
)

text = alt.Chart(source).mark_text(dx=-15, dy=3, color='white').encode(
    x=alt.X('sum(yield):Q', stack='zero'),
    y=alt.Y('variety:N'),
    detail='site:N',
    text=alt.Text('sum(yield):Q', format='.1f')
)

bars + text
```

[image]

With faceting it can look like this:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import random


source=data.barley()
source['group'] = [random.choice(['A', 'B']) for num in range(source.shape[0])]

bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('sum(yield):Q', stack='zero'),
    y=alt.Y('variety:N'),
    color=alt.Color('site')
)

text = alt.Chart(source).mark_text(dx=-15, dy=3, color='white').encode(
    x=alt.X('sum(yield):Q', stack='zero'),
    y=alt.Y('variety:N'),
    detail='site:N',
    text=alt.Text('sum(yield):Q', format='.1f')
)

(bars + text).facet(row='group')
```

[image]

Comment: it's different example, it's not working for grouped stacked bar plot

Comment: @seblful Please provide a [mre] of what you want to do, that includes sample data in the question so that it is possible to copy paste your code and help